# searching YouTube for videos with specific range of views eg. between 9,000,000 and 11,000,000

Tags: search, view, youtube, count

first time posting.

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how I can search on YouTube for, let's say, music video's that have been viewed between a set number of times. Like the title says for example, between 9 and 11 million times.

One reason I want to do this is because I want to find good music that I haven't heard before. The logic I'm working on is that the Got Talent type video's that get viewed millions of times are generally viewed that many times for one of two reason. 1) they're amazing. 2) they're embarrassingly horrible.

And though I don't think a song being popular will necessarily mean I'll like it, I'm hoping this method will be successful to some degree.

Another reason is to look for trailers for independent films with a similar logic as above. Though with these movies I think I only hear about them six months to a year after they've been released because they're flying under the radar.

If I were to be able to search for movie trailers with 'x' number of views though.. for example, between 500,000 and a million, maybe I'd be able to find movies that I'll like quicker than via time passing and them getting mentioned to me by a friend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've wanted to be able to perform these kind of searches for awhile now.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use YouTube API v3.

I havent written this exact request but it looks like you can list videos then filter by 'Chart' = 'mostPopular'

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Perhaps a bit of background reading on the API would help too...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Answer (score 0):

First off, you would need the [Youtube Data API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library). "v3" means nothing because it's simply the current version, like "Windows 10."

The API lets you get a video's view count, but doesn't put it in a range like *9 million to 11 million*.

Youtube's own search function is pretty sophisticated. For instance, 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=movie+trailer&search_sort=video_view_count&filters=month. This gives all results for "movie trailer," within the last month, sorted by view count. You can customize the URL, i.e. "week" instead of month would return only trailers from the last week. Or year, etc. Essentially this is a "Videos: List: MostPopular" query, with subject filter.

I have a few Youtube API scripts, and I hardly think it's worth the hassle to do it that way when Youtube's advanced search get you 99% there. If you did, you would need to to a [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) query for a given subject (i.e. "movie trailer"). Limited to a given time frame (i.e. last month). Then for each video ID, make a [Videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) query to get its view count. Then print all, sorted by views.